# Problemas ao imprimir código de barras em impressora EPSON LX-300 II

Tags: java

Estou tentando imprimir um código de barras na impressora EPSON LX-300 II, porém não está funcionando.

Estou utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
(Esc char)(B0500001800000000011151113939183000157550000000000091111023116
```

Que está de acordo com este manual, na página C-195:  http://doc.stoq.com.br/Epson/ESCP_Part_1.pdf

Já estou imprimindo um texto, porém, quando envio o comando de código de barras, a impressora interrompe a impressão.

O comando está correto? Esta impressora suporte impressão de código de barras?

Comment: Pegue um manual ESC/P da LX-300 II mesmo, senão vai sofrer à toa. Eu recomendaria você gerar as barras no seu código, e mandar pra impressora no modo gráfico (em ESC/P você manda o código de modo gráfico, a quantidade de caracteres, e os bytes dos pontos a imprimir, que no caso da barra vai ficar alternando em 0 e 255). Veja se isso ajuda http://esupport.epson-europe.com/FileDetails.aspx?lng=en-GB&data=6p8Gbf6kzcDjBDX5CN0IhYGAuQVqVCJs&id=18162

Comment: Já peguei o manual da própria LX-300 II e ele é exatamente igual a esse. E a impressão em modo gráfico também é um comando, logo, não sei se é viável, porém irei fazer essa tentativa.

Comment: A vantagem de você usar o modo gráfico é que se precisar amanhã ou depois trocar de impressora, fica muito mais fácil de adaptar. O modo gráfico ESC/P é muito mais aceito do que os modos de código de barras de alguns modelos.